# Search file by Name (using java, lucene or tech stack)

Tags: java, spring, apache, lucene

I have lots of image files and I want to search specific file by its name. I'm looking for suggestions to implement this using Java.

**Note:** I have used Apache lucene but it didn't work for image files. I think it searches by file content.

Please suggest what is the best technology that can be used to search files by name in large volumes of image files (in TB).

---

**EDIT**

Example:

User enters 'Engine', it should give results as like:

X60_031004_P05_16_AJ126SC_ENGINE_COVER_AWD_2.jt X60_031004_P05_16_AJ127SC_ENGINE_COVER.jt

Comment: What is lots? 100.000? 1 million? 100 million?

Comment: Lots means, the shared drive has 12 to 15 folders containing image files and size is in TB. (Approx 50k files in one folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`, like so:

```
    File root = new File("C:\\");
    String fileName = "Engine";
    String[] extensions = {"jt"};
    boolean recursive = true;
    Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, extensions, recursive);
    for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        File file = (File) iterator.next();
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().contains(fileName.toLowerCase()))
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Comment: I have not tried FileUtils but I think FileUtils will not scale on time line by considering drive size or volumes of files. Though I will give a try .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lucene for searching file names or in general image meta data. And it's probably the better solution than FileUtils especially if you wanna have all the nice "SearchEngine" features.

I do not have any experience with this kind of requirement but i would do it like this:

- Metadata extraction with Apache Tika (https://tika.apache.org/)
- Metadata indexing and searching with Apache Lucene
- Dedicated Storage for the images itself with a reference inside the Lucene index

Comment: Thanks. I tried with indexing and searching with Apache Lucene but it didn't worked when I point data directory to image/it files drive path. I tried it on PDF files and it worked, I think lucene output the file names based on file contents as image file not having any contents (text ) , not returning me file name/path

Comment: well you can index the path as a separate field. For my understanding you can define your own index structure. so you take informations from tika and index them in any field, lets say a stringfield which you call path or something. And if you don't want to search for this informations you can just use a StoredField.